# How to use object as value in dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here's the code:

```
import datetime
local = {};
class name:
     x = 0
     y = 0
     time = 0
     PCH = []
     FCC_Queue = []

t = datetime.time(0, 0, 0)
p = name()
p.x = 10
p.y = 20.0
p.time = t.second 
PCH.append('xyz','abc',1,15.0)
FCC_Queue.append(10.0,20.0,30.0)
local['Obj1'] = p
```

1. How do I access the value of p.x from the dict local['Obj1']?
2. Also, how do I access a list value e.g. PCH[1] from the dict local['Obj1']?

Comment: Have you tried localhostrecord['Obje1'].x? For your second question about 2 lists please provide sample code.

Comment: I have given you code you can see there...and in case if i want to search for a value present inside mylist what should i have to write as condition of if statement

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can and your code works.

To access the `x` of your object is as simple as

```
localhostrecord['Obje1'].x
```

To access the list you do the same and then treat this as a simple list

```
localhostrecord['Obje1'].PCH
# e.g. access second element of PCH list
localhostrecord['Obje1'].PCH[1]
```

Comment: as my PCH list contain 3 variable and if i want to access 2nd value than can i write  local['obj1'].PCH[2]

Comment: and in case if i want to search for a value present inside mylist what should i have to write as condition of if statement

Comment: I updated the answer with the example to access 2nd value. This is a standard list so treat this as a list. If you need more help on lists you should post a new question